# SQL Server Replication, How to Synch. a Subscriber gone offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, sql-server-2005-express

We are using SQL Sever 2005 replication for out application. Every thing is working fine without any problems. However, recently we ran into a situation to which I have no solution.

We use merge replication with the publisher(SQL Sever 2005) in one geography and the subscribers(SQL Sever 2005 express) in multiple other geographies. Because of network issues at the subscriber location, the subscriber is not able to connect to the publisher and hence not able to synchronize. A few tables in the subscriber have reached the allotted range and we are now unable to insert entries into them.

Is there any way I can resolve this issue? I could think of a few but not sure how to proceed with them:
i. Take a backup of the subscriber db, put it on a different machine. Synchronize and restore back the db.
ii. Copy all the data from (modified/inserted) into the Publisher (manually), reset the synchronization between the publisher and the said subscriber.

I am not very sure the above choices are feasible. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the right solution here to get that site back onto the network?

Comment: Hi Karlesn, 
Yes I agree, but due to the nature of the work conditions they are not able to bring back the connection.

Comment: Also this problem might reoccur considering the nature of the industry where the app. is used.

Comment: Which server is acting in the role of Distributor or are you running a remote Distributor? Also, are you using Push or Pull Subscribers? Are you using Client or Server Subscriptions? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151170(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Hi John,
The Publisher is acting as the distributor. We are using Pull subscribers.